# Dynamic Radio Buttons won't Call Second JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, radio-button

I dynamically create radio buttons based on a dropdown with name `afl_round`. This works seamlessly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var valueCheck;
    jQuery('#afl_round').on( 'change', function () {
         afl_round = $('#afl_round').val();
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'call_slate_radio_buttons_ownership',
            afl_round: afl_round,
        },
         success:function(output){
             jQuery('#radio_buttons').html( output );
         }
     });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

I then want to be able to change `#ownership_table` based on the selection from the radio buttons. However, I'm finding that this script doesn't seem to run at all.

When I generate the radio buttons direct through `php` instead of javascript the table works perfectly fine with the code below so I feel it must have something to do with the cascading nature of the javascript?

The scripts are ordered sequentially as they are written here in the webpage.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
   jQuery('input:radio[name=afl_slate]').on( 'change', function () {
         afl_slate = $('input:radio[name=afl_slate]:checked').val();
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
       data: {
            action: 'call_slate_ownership_table',
            afl_slate: afl_slate,
        },
         success:function(output){
             jQuery('#ownership_table').html( output );
         }
     });
    }).click();
});
</script>
```

I would appreciate any input people have as I am sure it's something reasonably simple that I've overlooked.

Thanks in advance.

---

As requested in comments, I've copied a simplified version of my php file code to help. As mentioned above the first code successfully generates the radio buttons. The second code doesn't generate anything.....unless I hard code the radio buttons in html. So I don't believe there is anything wrong with either of these php files. My thinking is that a link between the javascripts isn't there.

```
function get_slate_radio_buttons_ownership(){
global $wpdb;

$round = $_POST['afl_round'];
$myQuery = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT ds_slate_name, ds_slate_id FROM afl_master WHERE round = '.$round.' GROUP BY ds_slate_id');

if($myQuery){
$check = 0;
foreach ( $myQuery as $result ) 
    {
if($check == 0){$checked=' checked="checked"';} else{$checked='';}
echo'<input type="radio" name="afl_slate" value="'.$result->ds_slate_id.'"'.$checked.'/> '.$result->ds_slate_name.'<br>';
$check = $check + 1;
    }
}

echo'<br>';
wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_slate_radio_buttons_ownership', 'get_slate_radio_buttons_ownership');
add_action('wp_ajax_call_slate_radio_buttons_ownership', 'get_slate_radio_buttons_ownership');
```

---

```
function get_slate_ownership_table(){
global $wpdb;

$slate = $_POST['afl_slate'];
$myQuery = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM afl_master WHERE ds_slate_id = "'.$slate.'" ORDER by ds_selected DESC');

echo '<div style="overflow-x:auto;">';
echo '<table>';
echo "<tr><th>Player Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>"; 

if($myQuery){
foreach ( $myQuery as $result ) 
{
$ds_value = number_format(ROUND(1000*$result->dreamTeamPoints/$result->ds_salary_hist,1),1);

    echo '<tr><td>'.$result->player_name.'</td><td>'.$ds_value.'x</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';

wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_slate_ownership_table', 'get_slate_ownership_table');
add_action('wp_ajax_call_slate_ownership_table', 'get_slate_ownership_table');
```

Comment: Your first script does not work or second one?

Comment: The first script generates the radio buttons perfectly. The second one however doesn't run (nothing renders on the website).........If I hard code the radio buttons using HTML (same code that is in the php file) then the second script above works perfectly so to me the script is fine. I just can't get them to work together at the same time. I've never tried to cascade javascripts like this so I'm assuming I'm missing some sort of fundamental?

Comment: You mean your second script is not able to generate the radio buttons? Please add your html code.

Comment: No, the second script is supposed to generate a table. But nothing is generated.......However, if I cut and paste the html code from script 1 into the webpage then the second script successully generates the table. I don't believe there is anything wrong with either html code. My thinking is that there is an issue with the link between the two javascripts, I'll copy and paste html code into the question for completeness.

Comment: I've included code above